# Best way to create and connect a Windows Phone 8 app to a database (SQL Server preferably)

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, azure, windows-phone-8

I am creating a Windows Phone 8 app using C# and XAML, that scrapes a website for data about what is poisonous to pets. Once a user enters the product, it goes to the url of the poison list on that website concatenated with the name of the product. For example, for chocolate:
www.petpoisonhelpline.com/poison/ + chocolate/

I am thinking of creating  a database of the product names and urls using the [complete poison list](http://www.petpoisonhelpline.com/poisons/) the website has.

That way I can implement a search suggestion feature and also use the database to correctly go to the url of the product.

Now I need to find a way to create that database and connect it to my app. I have searched the internet for suggestions and so far I have come across SQLite and SQL Server Compact Toolbox; and using LINQ to SQL. The problem is I don't even know if the database should be local or hosted on Azure so I don't know which tutorials to look for.

Is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk9yw1t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) feasible for what I'm trying to accomplish?

I'm sorry if this seems like a repeated question. But I have honestly tried to search for a similar question but I since I don't know how to approach the problem, I don't know which answers apply to what I'm trying to do.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone or Silverlight based application can't connect directly to SQL server database. Possible options are to :

1. use local database (such as SQLite, SQL CE),
2. look into Windows Azure's [Mobile
   Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-get-started/)
   if you want to store data in Azure
3. if you want to use SQL server database, create web service to bridge
   windows phone application to database. Then you can develop web
   service to connect to database following that MSDN article, and
   connect windows phone application to the web service. Reference [on how to connect windows phone application to wcf service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196996/Consuming-WCF-Service-from-Windows-7-Phone-Applica).

.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I started using SQL CE. It seems okay but I am running into errors with finding the path to my database. I am trying to look for an answer on stackoverflow. Thanks once again!

Comment: you're welcome. Don't forget to accept this answer to confirm you got proper answer to the question ([more info about accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)). Don't hesitate to post another question about that error if you find it difficult to solve.